# ddr: Is there any significant delta between the different strobes?

Tags: sdram, ddr, dram

In a DDR memory, during a read, output data from the DDR is aligned on the strobe. There is one strobe per 8-bit:

- UDQS/LDQS for a 16-bit-wide DDR
- DQS[0-3] for a 32-bit-wide DDR

Is there any significant delta between the strobes of the same DDR chip? 'Significant' means: can I use one strobe for all the bit? I have a custom-made DDR controller in a FPGA and I would like to use one strobe for the entire data set.

Comment: How confident are you about the source of the memory? If each 8 bits comes from a separate chip, expect skew between them. Are you driving them at the nameplate rate? If you are underclocking them by a factor of 4, your timing budget has more room for error.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, obviously, it's only one DDR chip. I thought the question was clear enough. I'm editing it.

Comment: @DaveTweed, Thank you. You can put your comment as an answer. So basically, at the 'exit' of a 16-bit DDR chip, the two balls or pins [UL]DQS are in sync or quasi in sync. Multiple DQS is provided more for convenience of routing (or if you use [UL]DQM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timing budget on a DDR memory interface is very tight to begin with. If you use only a single strobe, you'll have to carefully length-match all 33 traces as a group to minimize skew. If you use individual strobes, then you only need to length-match groups of 9 traces at a time. The matching between groups can be a little more relaxed.